# Handle same intent-filter for different activity

Tags: android, intentfilter

In my app I have two `activities` which appear like two different apps (separate icons on the homescreen) to the user. Now both of them have an intent-filter listening for USB-devices plugged in. The problem is, that when in `Activity A` and I insert the USB-device to the tablet, automatically `Activity B` starts.
What I want to achieve is:

```
Activity A -> insert USB -> stay in Activity A and do something with the USB
Activity B -> insert USB -> stay in Activity B and do something else with the USB
```

Here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mypackage.myapp"
    android:versionCode="100"
    android:versionName="1.0.0-dev" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/my_icon"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="mypackage.ActivityA"
            android:icon="@drawable/my_icon"
            android:label="@string/ActivityA"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />

            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/lib_device_filter" />

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="mypackage.ActivityB"
            android:icon="@drawable/another_icon"
            android:label="@string/ActivityB"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/lib_device_filter" />

        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Yes and no: Requirements changed, so both apps were combined to one single app

Answer (score 2):

I found with the same issues in a project and I would like to share with you the 
implemented solution.

First of all, I made a activity called DumpActivity. This activity just implement the intent filters to listen when the USB is plugged, that's all. When the activity is launched, immediatly it's finished to return to the previous activity. At this point, the previous activity (Activity A or B in your example) is able to interact with the USB.

```
/**
 * This activity have the intent filters of the USB (see AndroidManifest.xml).
 *
 * When it is the first time that the USB microphones are plugged, this activity is launched.
 * This is a solution to disable the popup dialog when a USB device is connected.
 *
 * When this activity is launched, immediately it is destroyed to return to the previous
 * activity
 */

public class DumpActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (getIntent().getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED)) {
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        if (intent.getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED)) {
            finish();
        }
    }
 }
```

Then, in the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mypackage.myapp"
    android:versionCode="100"
    android:versionName="1.0.0-dev" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USB_PERMISSION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.device" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/my_icon"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="mypackage.DumpActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/lib_device_filter">
            </meta-data>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/lib_device_filter">
            </meta-data>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="mypackage.ActivityA"
            android:icon="@drawable/my_icon"
            android:label="@string/ActivityA"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="mypackage.ActivityB"
            android:icon="@drawable/another_icon"
            android:label="@string/ActivityB"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

NOTE 1: The intent filter must be only in this activity!

NOTE 2: This solution is useful if you need to interact with the USB in different activities and you don't want to see the popup dialog everytime you plug the USB.

Marc G.